# ASP.NET core Dependency Injection Singleton Cache Instance not the same object across classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am trying to create a cache manager that is injected via dependency injection in `ASP.NET Core` by doing this

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton<ICacheManager, CacheManager>())
      .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

in `Program.cs` so I can access this in one of my controller classes and my `Startup.cs` class (both of the constructors have `ICacheManager` in them)

However whenever I update the cache in `Startup.cs` it does not seem to get reflected when my other controller with this dependency reads it. This is a singleton instance and my understanding is that the same object instance will be accessed for both classes. Am I missing something?

In my `Startup.cs` I simply have

```cs
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ICacheManager cacheManager)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    _cacheManager= cacheManager;
}
```

where I will add data to the cache in `Startup.cs`

In my controller I have in the constructor

```cs
public ChatRoomController(ICacheManager cacheManager)
{
    _cacheManager = cacheManager;
}
```

and when I try to utilize data in the cacheManager (a concurrent dictionary) I see that it is empty.

Comment: Please show your code from `startup.cs` and `controller` class

Comment: Why are you not using the standard way of dependency injection for asp.net? It's explained pretty good in the Microsoft docs and shown in the default asp project templates

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
```

No need to assign or create an instance...

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<ICacheManager, CacheManager>()   
    }
```

Since the...

> injection of the service into the constructor of the class where it's
> used. The framework takes on the responsibility of creating an
> instance of the dependency and disposing of it when it's no longer
> needed.

So keep your `ChatRoomController` the same and let me know if that works

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thanks, but I also need to use the cache manager in the Startup class so wouldn't I need it in the Startup's constructor? It seems like two instances are being created one for the startup class and one for the controller class

Comment: It seems like for some reason in the startup class another instance of the cache manager is being instantiated while across my controllers the same cache manager is being shared so there are two instances of it even though I registered it as a singleton

Comment: try to use it in the startup class, add a Dummy value, and then try to read it, but without assigning it to a variable.

Comment: I got it to work by setting it as another paramter in the Configure method not doing anything in ConfigureServices. Do you know why this may be?

Comment: please update your question or provide the solution in a new answer to understand